# Default value of <scope> in Sublime Text 3 snippets

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

What is default value of `<scope>` for Sublime Text 3 snippets or what value this field should have, to force ST3 to display auto-completion list, with particular snippet at the top, when I'm typing something in `.php` document?

I have following Sublime Text 3 snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<?php echo ${0:$SELECTION}; ?>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>echo</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

I tested it with `<scope>source.html</scope>`, `<scope>source.php</scope>` and with `<scope>` tag removed and Sublime Text 3 never displayed me an auto-completion dialog, as I was typing something in `.php` file. I always have to `Tools > Snippets...` menu or keyboard shortcut, that I binded to this menu item.

Comment: It should be `text.html`, not `source.html`

Comment: List of all scopes available: https://gist.github.com/iambibhas/4705378